# how to set tab at specific position of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

how to set tab bar at specific position of layout as shown in image....
in xml layout i set like three relative view one after another and tab host i put in third layout and also there is second layout is in proper position in view but problem with tab layout only.....

[image]

now this is xml file.....

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/userprofile_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/novak_djokovic_medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="NAME" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_sex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/se_1_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=",MALE" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_age"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/se_1_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/se_1_sex"
            android:text="18" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_country"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/se_1_sex"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="UK" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_city"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/se_1_sex"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/se_1_country"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="LONDON" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_bgphoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bgphoto32x32" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_userphoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/se_1_bgphoto"
            android:background="@drawable/userphoto32x32" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/se_1_edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/se_1_userphoto"
            android:background="@drawable/edit32x32" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="12" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/we"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/we"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/we"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/we"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/we"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/we"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="12323" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="3" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/we"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/we"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="123" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl112"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl113"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" >
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl114"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" >
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/s_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is class file...

```
public class settings extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings1);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.s_pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you need to position this view inside the parent view

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/s_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

you can do define a parent relative layout which will occupy the half screen and than you can align the above layout as the `layout_below="@+id/define your above  id here "`